# Dynamically changing class in v-text-field in default slot

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to dynamically change font-size in v-text-field default slot based on the length of the text. However, it seems that v-text-field ignores any specification I specify in the  section.

Here is the code

```
        <v-text-field
          v-model="attr.name"
          hide-details
          :readonly="true"
          class="core-select"
          label="Core Attribute"
        >
          <template
            v-slot:default
          >
            <div :class="attrNameStyle[0]">
              {{ attr.name }}
            </div>
          </template>
        </v-text-field>
```

I have verified that attrNameStyle[0] is gets set correctly, however that style never gets applied to the default slot. I can change the way input slot looks via this CSS class `.v-text-field__slot input { ... }` however, I can't update that CSS dynamically.

Thanks for help!

Edit: Adding more context.

```
.core-select {
  width: 180px;
}

.short-core-select {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

attrNameStyle[0] is set to either '', or 'short-core-select'.

Comment: Can you provide more code? The CSS classes core-select and whatever attrNameStyle[0] comes out to be may be conflicting.

Comment: More context added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `v-text-field__slot` is working, you could edit that CSS from a higher level.

```
<v-text-field
      v-model="attr.name"
      hide-details
      hide-details
      class="core-select"
      :class="attrNameStyle[0]"
      label="Core Attribute"
    >
      <template>
        <div>
          {{ attr.name }}
        </div>
      </template>
    </v-text-field>
```

```css
<style>
  .short-core-select .v-text-field__slot {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
</style>
```